# Why does creating a new object inside local function results in a faster runtime?

Tags: c#, linked-list, reverse, local-functions

hello I'm currently doing some LeetCode exercises and I'm failing to understand why I have a faster runtime on the first code sample than the second on this reverse list problem.
the linked list is like so:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     public int val;
 *     public ListNode next;
 *     public ListNode(int val=0, ListNode next=null) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.next = next;
 *     }
 * }
 */
```

**With local function create a new Node and make it the beggining of the list**

- Runtime: 94 ms
- Memory: 39 MB

```
public ListNode ReverseList(ListNode head) {
    if(head == null){
        return null;
    }
    
    ListNode AddNodeToBeginning(ListNode source, int val)
    {
        return new ListNode(val, source);
    };

    ListNode res = null;
    while(head != null){
        res = AddNodeToBeginning(res, head.val);
        head = head.next;
    }
    return res;
}
```

**(without local function)**

- Runtime: 129 ms
- Memory: 38 MB

```
public ListNode ReverseList(ListNode head) {
    if(head == null){
        return null;
    }

    ListNode res = null;
    while(head != null){
        res = new ListNode(head.val, res);
        head = head.next;
    }
    return res;
}
```

My question is does why does using the local function to create a new node **always** gives me faster runtime

the question is https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/submissions/

Comment: Please post a sample input linked-list so we can reproduce the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: I would have expected the method in the first example to be inlined, effectively making the examples identical. If there is a significant difference I would suspect either some problem with the measurement, or some compiler artifact. I would suggest testing with benchmark .Net to see if the runtime makes any difference.

Comment: the test samples are:
[1,2,3,4,5], 

[1,2]
and 
[]

Comment: I actually get very slightly slower results using the first version. Have you tested it with BenchmarkDotNet?